# Can a function be represented as 2 different power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, divergent-series

Find the power series representation for ()=1/x+2 cant i write the power series as $$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x+2}.
$$
so I am a little confused because cant I write the series as
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{1-(-x-1)} \quad or \quad f(x) =\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-(\frac{-x}{2})}
$$
these different representations results in different intervals of convergence can someone help me

Comment: sorry i wrote ()=1/x+2 twice

Comment: The first expands about $x = -1$ and has (open) convergence interval of $(-2,0)$ for a radius of $1.$ The second expands about $x = 0$ and has (open) convergence interval of $(-2,2)$ for a radius of $2.$ In each case, the convergence interval is the maximal (open) interval centered at the expansion point, and such that the interval does not contain the singularity at $x=-2.$ If you were to expand about $x = -\frac{3}{2}$ (i.e. powers of $x+\frac{3}{2}),$ then the radius would be $\frac{1}{2}.$ If you were to expand about $x = 28$ (i.e. powers of $x-28),$ then the radius would be $30.$

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help 